# Checking if a span with data attribute exists in if statement

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to search if any element exists with the data attribute 'datanamed' with the username specified.

The code is below: in an if statement, which doesn't work properly.

```
if($('*[datanamed=" + username + "]') === undefined){ 

}
else {

}
```

Comment: `if (elements.length) {...}`

Answer (score 2):

jQuery returns a jQuery object, it cannot be *undefined*, you should use the `length` property of the retuned jQuery object instead, also note that if `username` is a variable, the string concatenation in your code is wrong, a standard IDE can show the problem(*missing quotes*):

```
if ( $('*[datanamed="' + username + '"]' ).length === 0 ) { 
   // doesn't exist
} else {
   // exists
}
```

Note that unversal selector `*` is very expensive. Before filtering, it selects all the existing elements in the DOM. If there are only several elements that can have this attribute you can use `.filter()` method:

```
if ( $('a, div, span').filter('[datanamed="' + username + '"]').length === 0 ) { 
   // doesn't exist
} else {
   // exists
}
```

**PS**: The proper syntax of HTML5 `data-*` attributes is `data-*`, your attribute is invalid. It should be `data-named`.